# Fetch One row per AlbumID from a Photos table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table with Photos, allowing multiple rows per AlbumID: 
Photos (photoID, photo,caption,albumID). 
Albums (albumID,albumTitle)

I want a list of albumTitle and one photo for that albumID. 
There are multiple photos in Photos table for a single albumID.

Can you provide a sql statement to select only one Photo per album id?

Thanks in advance!
Avi

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using the `Max(photoId)`:

```
Select a.albumId, a.albumTitle, p.photoId, p.photo, p.caption
From Albums a
    Inner Join Photos p On a.albumId = p.albumId
    Inner Join (
        Select Max(photoId) maxPhotoId, albumId
        From Photos
        Group By albumId
    ) t On p.photoId = t.maxPhotoId And a.albumId = t.albumId
```

Comment: Thanks this query works

Comment: @Avi -- np, glad I could help!  Not sure why it was downvoted though...

Comment: sgeddes-- sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and did it by mistake.Now if I am trying to voteup it says u need more reputations for it....Thanks a lot.. u saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AlbumID, MIN(PhotoID)
FROM PHOTOS
GROUP BY AlbumID
```

Comment: John Puttman, thanks for the answer. I want to get list of photo and album title so I tried your query in where clause like this ....................................................................select photo from Photos where PhotoId in(
SELECT AlbumId, MIN(PhotoID)
FROM Photos 
GROUP BY AlbumId).............but I am getting error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Answer (score 0):

this will return only 1 of each instance of each albumID and a photo

```
SELECT DISTINCT `albumID `, `photo` FROM `Photos`;
```

and then you can:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT `albumID `, `photo`
FROM 
  `Photos` 
INNER JOIN
  `Albums`
  ON `Albums.albumID` = `Photos.albumID`
   AND `Albums.albumTitle` = `albumTitle`
```